# Can't add Indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation

**Problem:**
Whenever i use my Tab key that usually add indentation to my code, now it's not working anymore. Instead of adding an indentation it just navigating through every single visual studio code element like bottom bar, back button, search input, vs code layout, elements of left sidebar etc.

i want it working like usually, what should i do in order to fix it?

What I tried:

1. searching 'indent' keyword in keyboard shortcuts but never find it. (but i still i found the outdent key)
2. resetting my user settings (not working)
3. search it through vs code json file (can't find key that associate with tab key)

Comment: I don't know why yours has gone wrong, but <Ctrl> + ] (square bracket) and <Ctrl> + [ indent and unindent, if that keeps you going until you find the answer.